# Not able to run carousel code as a widget on a website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   **This is a code of a carousel feature that I intend to modify and add as a widget to a website , but I am facing issues in getting the carousel to work. Please help.** 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
        background-image: none;
        color: #f4511e;
    }

    .carousel-indicators li {
        border-color: #f4511e;
    }

    .carousel-indicators li.active {
        background-color: #f4511e;
    }

    .item h4 {
        font-size: 19px;
        line-height: 1.375em;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        margin: 10px 5px 120px 5px;
    }

    .item span {
        font-style: normal;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>BPM Provides</h2></div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
        <h3>SOLUTION</h3>
        <h4>"This company is the best. I am so happy with the result!"<br><span style="font-style:normal;">Michael Roe, Vice President, Comment Box</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>"One word... WOW!!"<br><span style="font-style:normal;">John Doe, Salesman, Rep Inc</span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h4>"Could I... BE any more happy with this company?"<br><span style="font-style:normal;">Chandler Bing, Actor, FriendsAlot</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is a code of a carousel feature that I intend to modify and add as a widget to a website, but I am facing issues in getting the carousel to work.

Comment: Can you clarify your question,  please? i have got all works in Plunker.

Comment: I agree. Seems to work fine http://www.bootply.com/OMD1JZgEgk

Comment: It is working fine as a webpage, but not when I put this code as a widget on a website.